# How can I install Windows through an ASUS P5Q's orange and white SATA ports?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, motherboard, raid

I have an [ASUS P5Q motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5Q/), which apparently has two SATA controllers - the standard Intel one (red ports), and a Marvell controller (orange and white ports).

I need the Intel controller to be in RAID mode, as I have a three-disk array that I'm attempting to restore. The data (and operating system) on these drives is not currently accessible.

The restoration process needs to be done from an OS, so I want to install Windows onto a drive or two connected to the Marvell controller. However, it seems that no matter how I set up ASUS Drive Xpert in BIOS, the drive or drives are not recognized.

How can I install Windows onto one or two drive(s) using only the Marvell-controlled SATA ports?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the [Marvell driver](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5Q/HelpDesk_Download/) (the one that matches your Windows version and bit-level) to Windows Setup so that it can recognize the Marvell controller and, in turn, see the drives.

Comment: That makes sense. I've been trying to install XP, but it seems the XP install I have can only load drivers from a floppy. Trying 7 now.

Comment: I can't seem to get Windows to recognize the driver - I've tried a few versions of it from ASUS's website. I get a "no signed device drivers were found" message from Win7 setup.

Answer (score 0):

so I've been struggling a lot to get just a plain win 7 copy onto the two hdd's (Using the Marvell controller SATA port 0 & 1; orange and white)
So ASUS calls this the Drive Xpert and it uses the Marvell 88SE6111 SATA Controller, and the only place I could find the driver is , yes on ASUS website, but under Vista 64 and further more you have too click on "Show More" otherwise you just get the RAID drivers and not the Marvell 88SE6111.
The bad part is that this is and MSI driver installer so it wouldn't help in the installation process.

I ended up resetting the Bios to Factory, Selecting the drive Xpert to speedup (presume Raid 0), and Storage config to AHCI, and Win 7 installed onto the two drive with any tweaks or changes or having to load addition drivers....

Further more I added two more hdd's, changed the Bios Storage setting to RAID, created the volume (in my case another RAID 0) , booted into Win 7 , installed the drivers from ASUS website for WIN 7 64 RAID controller, and saw my drives :)

Hopes this helps